# Записать цвет кодом

Tags: html

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, записать цвет шестнадцатеричным кодом.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Цвет можно и в paint определить. С помощью пипетки выбрать нужный цвет, "Паллитра" > "изменить паллитру" > "определить цвет". Ну а дальше просто задать цвет как

```
style="color: rgb(R,G,B);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нет фотошопа -- используйте [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/). Реализует многие его возможности совершенно бесплатно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно FastStone Capture,а если бесплатная вроде у [PicPick](http://www.picpick.org/) или на худой конец дополнение в браузере

[Eye Dropper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hmdcmlfkchdmnmnmheododdhjedfccka?hl=ru&hc=search&hcp=ext) если в Chrome,[ColorZilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/colorzilla/) если Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

вот это программка вообще самая уматная !!!pixie.exe!!!
определяет цвет под курсором мыши в буфер копирует тот самый шестнадцатиричный код нажатием клавишь ctrl+alt+C...
рекомендую так как прежде определить цвет через фотошоп картинку ещё нужно туда всунуть..